# How to expire mssql db password

Tags: sql-server, database, passwords

How can I get my mssql db password manually expired? I need to test a certain case. Is there something like "alter user myuser password expire" as it is in Oracle?

Or how can I set the expiration date for one specific user from sql (not for all)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a password expiration policy for SQL Authentication in SQL Server. When you create new login you can setup `CHECK_EXPIRATION = ON` and `CHECK_POLICY= ON` which will setup expiration for SQL Server Login.

This [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161959.aspx) link should help you more

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, what I need is to expire the password manually; I am not interested in setting the policies on and off for expiration.